# "Cannot GET /" with express in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I have build a website of contact us form which takes email, name and gender of the user and put them all in a output.txt file.
At the time of creation of website, the website was running. But today when I was attempting it to open once again, there came an error stating Cannot GET /.

I am using pug as a template engine for express and have given it some styling using css.

My code of the javascript file is:-

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

// Express specific stuff
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Pug specific stuff
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Endpoints
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    name = req.body.name;
    age = req.body.age;
    gender = req.body.gender;
    number = req.body.number;
    email = req.body.email;

    let output = `Name: ${name}, Gender: ${gender}, Email: ${email}`;

    fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', output);

    const params = { 'message': 'Form successfully submitted' };

    res.status(200).render('index.pug', params);

});

// Starting the server
app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`The server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

Please help me!!

My Pug source code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Contact Us Form</title>
style
    include ../static/style.css
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name = "name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        <input type="text" name = "gender" placeholder="Enter your gender" required>
        <input type="email" name = "email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share the snippet of the Pug template that you use to make the POST request so that we can see the problem in a greater detail?

Comment: @NicholasD , I have updated my question with Pug template

Answer (score 0):

It seems It should be as :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
})

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  name = req.body.name;
  age = req.body.age;
  gender = req.body.gender;
  number = req.body.number;
  email = req.body.email;    
  let output = `Name: ${name}, Gender: ${gender}, Email: ${email}`;
  fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', output);
  const params = { 'message': 'Form successfully submitted' };
  // If need to redirect then
  res.redirect('/redirect-route');
  // If Re-render Page again
  res.render('index', params );
})
```

Comment: I edit code just. please review it again.

Comment: @ShivamSingh, Please refer this link to solve your issue https://www.sitepoint.com/build-simple-beginner-app-node-bootstrap-mongodb/